# Replace string in pandas dataframe keeping the frst occurance intact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df
Name    Statement 1
A       Value is favourable due to A favourable due to Q favourable due to U and unfavourable due to D
B       Value is favourable due to T favourable due to W favourable due to J and unfavourable due to O
C       Value is favourable due to U favourable due to D favourable due to H and unfavourable due to P
D       Value is favourable due to J favourable due to F favourable due to M and unfavourable due to Z
```

Is there any way to replace the string `"favourable due to"` with `","` except for the first occurrence.

Also the same thing needs to be done for the unfavourable part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Statement 1'] = df['Statement 1'].apply(lambda x: x[:27]+x[27:].replace(' favourable due to', ','))

print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
  Name                                                   Statement 1
0    A  Value is favourable due to A, Q, U and unfavourable due to D
1    B  Value is favourable due to T, W, J and unfavourable due to O
2    C  Value is favourable due to U, D, H and unfavourable due to P
3    D  Value is favourable due to J, F, M and unfavourable due to Z
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code in this solution?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
df['Statement 1'] = df['Statement 1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' favourable due to', ',').replace(',', ' favourable due to', 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name                                                   Statement 1
0    A  Value is favourable due to A, Q, U and unfavourable due to D
1    B  Value is favourable due to T, W, J and unfavourable due to O
2    C  Value is favourable due to U, D, H and unfavourable due to P
3    D  Value is favourable due to J, F, M and unfavourable due to Z
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I implemented the above code in mine and i got issue due to the ```","``` in the amount. Not all sentences in my input are same, so didnt see this issue before.

Before:
```Amount is 1,189M(38.5%) favourably driven by A 379M(12.26%) favourably driven by B 361M(11.7%)```
After:
```Amount is 1 favourably driven by189M(38.5%), A 379M(12.26%), B 361M(11.7%)```

Is there a way to tackle this?